# What is the django template tag to get the number of items returned in a result set?

Tags: django

What is the tag that displays the number of items returned in an object list? For example, in a view called `/search/q=my search text here` a list of articles are displayed that matches the user's search query. In the template I want to display the number of articles that were returned by the search.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use the template filter [length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length):

```
{{ articles|length }}
```

will display the length of articles list.

Comment: `count` will probably be more efficient since it doesn't need to evaluate the whole queryset, but will instead use another SQL request with `count(*)`.

Comment: @Guillaume, actually `length` just calls `len`, and Django is intelligent enough to do `count(*)` if the queryset is not yet evaluated. In fact, if you are going to iterate it anyway later, `len` can be *more* efficient, as it prevents you doing two db calls.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea Django was so clever about `length`. And you are obviously right about the fact that `len` *can* be more efficient.

Comment: In Django 1.4.3 {{qs|length}} and {{qs.count}} are incredibly different.  Django is not smart enough to do count(*) if the queryset hasn't been evaluated and the difference on large datasets is considerable. {{qs|length}} will iterate the queryset by default.

Comment: if you use "paginate_by" in your view it does not count the total, it displays to count on that page.

Comment: in Django 2.1.1 `len(queryset)` just runs `len(self._fetch_all())` which evaluates the queryset. As the docs say, better use `count` if you need only the number of results.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do this I think is:

```
{{ articles.count }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `count()` method gets the number of items retrieved by the queryset it is called on.

Comment: Use it like that `{{ articles.count }}`

Comment: One thing to note, though. `count` will run a SQL COUNT if the queryset has not already been evaluated. Then, when iterated over later, another DB query (SELECT) will be made. That's two queries. If you need the count before you actually loop through the queryset or such, `{{ articles|length }}` is more efficient.